# Google Stackdriver error reporting and source code snapshot

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sentry, stackdriver

Does google Stack driver error reporting have the ability to associate a error stack trace to the version of the source code that caused the error?

We can't find anything that lets you upload your source code or "symbol files" for a given release so that when an error happens it can show a few lines of code around that error. Just having a stack trace that says "main.py line 50 " is not helpful because it takes a significant amount of time to figure out which version of the code caused the problem and go back to git and figure out what "line 50" meant at the time.

Sentry.io does this. For each release, you [upload your source code](https://docs.sentry.io/learn/cli/releases/#managing-release-artifacts) and when an error occurs they match of the source code to the error for you and you can just see the lines of code around the error in the error details page. Here is an image. (Note that sentry shows you the source code in addition to stack trace line adapters.py line 487) [image]

Stackdrive does not have this functionality as far as I can tell. Right?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the [Stackdriver Debugger](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/?hl=en_US)

> Stackdriver Debugger is a feature of Google Cloud Platform that lets
>   you inspect the state of an application, at any code location, without
>   stopping or slowing down the running app. Stackdriver Debugger makes
>   it easier to view the application state without adding logging
>   statements. You can use Stackdriver Debugger with any deployment of
>   your application, including test, development, and production. The
>   debugger adds less than 10ms to the request latency only when the
>   application state is captured. In most cases, this is not noticeable
>   by users.

Comment: unfortunately that is not it. what i need is the source code to be associated with the stack trace. I added an image for that to the question.

Comment: I was taking a look at the Stackdriver debugger and saw this: https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/source-options
Is that not working for you?